# Date string to monthdate format

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert my date string to MonthDate format

Date string is in this format "08-07-2016 00:00:00"

I need this output:  July 8

I am trying `String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dt)` but it is not working.

Comment: Depending on the MonthDayPattern set in your culture, you may be able to use just `date.ToString("M")`

Comment: did you at least try one of the given answers?

Answer (score 6):

replace

```
String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dt)
```

with

```
String.Format("{0:MMMM d}", dt)
```

- `MMMM` is the name of the month
- `d` is the day without leading 0

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string.Format("{0:MMMM d}", dt);
```

In C# 6.0 you can do it like this:

```
$"{dt:MMMM d}";
```

With `"MMM"` you get the short version of each month. With `"MMMM"` you get the full name.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?:

```
date.ToString("MMMM d")
```

Example:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("08-07-2016 00:00:00");
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("MMMM d"));
```

Results to: 
July 8

Answer (score 1):

If your date is a string, try this :

```
string myDate = "08-07-2016 00:00:00";
DateTime myDateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
string myDateString = string.Format("{0: MMMM d}", myDateValue);
```